# Added or merging manifest sections with maven shade plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I create a "fat jar" using the maven shade plugin (version 2.4.3).

I want to merge the manifest sections from several jar's into the MANIFEST.MF file of the target (fat) jar. IFAIK this is not possible.

Second try is to add the needed manifest sections manually, using `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer`. However, i cannot get this working neither.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I only want to aggregate (or add) the attribute sections or [per-entry attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Per-Entry_Attributes).

Comment: Well this is hard since you can't just append one MANIFEST to another one, which is what `AppendingTransformer` does. Could you post a sample of what you want?

Comment: No, just adding is not possible (but is also not what i want). I *only* want to aggregate the *manifest sections*. See also the update.